# Why does the program terminate on startup without outputting anything?

Tags: c++, user-input

I made a C++ user input that detects when no value is being input, but it terminates the program on startup without outputting anything. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  bool entered = false;
  while(entered = false) {
    std::cout << "Please enter thy name: ";
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " + name;
    int length = name.length();
    if(length > 0) {
      std::cout << "Hello, " + name;
      entered = true;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Thou did not enter thy name";
    }
  }
}
```

I already made a similar program in Java with a similar format and that one works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop condition:

```
while(entered = false)
```

is wrong. Instead of comparing `false` and `entered`, you are assigning `false` to `entered`.

Instead, you need to do:

```
while(entered == false)
```

If you turn on warnings, for example with `-Wall`, the compiler will tell you that you are likely making a mistake here.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that your main function starts with `int` but I can't see `return 0`, remember that if your function is not `void` then it **must** return something.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `main` is an exception to the rule. This doesn't fix the OP's problem either.